# Rails Active Record items partitioning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, activerecord

So, this is a bit of an easier question. I have an active record object like so:

```
Item
  --id
  --attribute
```

I need to split up an array of "Item"s by the attribute key, so I want various array split like so.

```
[<#Item :id => 1, :attribute => 1>,<#Item :id => 4, :attribute => 1>,<#Item :id => 7, :attribute => 1>]
[<#Item :id => 2, :attribute => 2>,<#Item :id => 5, :attribute => 2>,<#Item :id => 8, :attribute => 2>]
[<#Item :id => 3, :attribute => 3>,<#Item :id => 6, :attribute => 3>,<#Item :id => 9, :attribute => 3>]
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you an array of arrays, where each subarray has the same `attribute`:

```
Items.all.group_by(&:attribute).values
```

Edit: since you are using `ActiveRecord`, you could group in the database. I'm more of a `DataMapper` guy myself, but this should be roughly it:

```
Items.find(:all, group: 'attribute')
```